# Possibility on huge MySQL database replication

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump

I have a mysql database with size 2.4TB which has lots of reads and writes happening continuously. I want to replicate this database as a backup. 
But it's almost impossible to get a dump from this database with it's size. Is it possible to create a slave replica without a dump of the master?

Answer (score 0):

Plan B:  Stop MySQL; copy the disk.

But first, turn on binlogging so that you will be able to sync up after you get the Slave going.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Take a snapshot (if your data is in LVM or ZFS) and copy that across.

2) Use xtrabackup.

Both of those approaches will be much faster, too.